# Retrieving user data from firebase database in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, duplicates

I'm using Firebase as my backend (Android, Java) and I'm having problem retrieving the username from the database to avoid duplicate data.

This is my database setup:

```
usernameTaken:
    [ID generated by push()]:
        Username: username
users:
    UidFromRegistration:
       Email: emailFromRegistration
       Username: username
```

I need to check if the new user choose an already registered username.

First I tried to save the data without the `push()` but I couldn't.

This is my code:

```
        private void checkUser() {

    String username = mUsernameSingUp.getText().toString().trim();

    mDatabase.child("takenUsernames").orderByChild("Username").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                registerUser();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Username already taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

private void registerUser() {

    //getting email, username and password from edit texts

    String username = mUsernameSingUp.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = mEmailSingUp.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = mPasswordSingUp.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if email, passwords and username are empty
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if the email, password and username are not empty
    //displaying a progress dialog

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //creating a new user
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        createNewUser(task.getResult().getUser());
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));

                    } else {
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}

private void createNewUser(FirebaseUser userFromRegistration) {

    String username = mUsernameSingUp.getText().toString().trim();
    String emailReg = userFromRegistration.getEmail();
    String userIdReg = userFromRegistration.getUid();

    Map<String, String> newUser = new HashMap<>();
    newUser.put("Username", username);
    newUser.put("Email", emailReg);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userIdReg).setValue(newUser);

    Map<String, String> usernameIsTaken = new HashMap<>();
    usernameIsTaken.put("Username", username);
    mDatabase.child("takenUsernames").push().setValue(usernameIsTaken);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view == mSingUpBtn) {
        checkUser();
    }

    if (view == mRegTv) {
        //open login activity when user taps on the already registered textview
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }

}
}
```

I was looking for a solution in the forum but everything I tried failed.

## **UPDATE:**

I updated the code above. I think I'm close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to see if the username has been already taken before creating a new user, something like:

```
mDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("Username").equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
             showError("Username already taken");
        else
             registerUser();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
})
```

And you don't need the node takenUsernames;
I use some "pseudo" code but I think is clear what to do.

Comment: Instead of registerUser(); should I put this: "mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) [...]"?

Comment: yep, also create the user's "users" database object

Comment: I've used a generic registerUser method to include all your registration business logic.

Comment: Ey, I'm sorry but I'm having a problem now with this code. When I include the "mAuth.createNewUser[...]" inside the if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) the app doesn't work.

If I put inside this code just the logic that store the registered data in the database, the app works. But I need to check the username after Firebase create a new user with email and password

Comment: Why do you need to check the username after Firebase creates a new user with email and password? I would check first that the username is unique, then I would create the Firebase User, then I would save the data in the database. What error are you getting?

Comment: Any error. Just the app display the "registering" message (this one:     progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show(); ) "for ever".

Comment: Have you debugged mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)? Is the task successful?

Comment: How can I do that? 
Okei, but this code works without the "username check part". But when I put de registerUser(); inside the if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) stop working displaying the "registering" message for unlimited time

Comment: Post entire Code. To debug you can put breakpoints in the code or use Log.d("My activity", "My message");  to print variables or messages. Read a guide on android debugging. You will need it.

Comment: You'r right. I'm new. I'm gonna try this. Thanks for your time.